# Find the top 10 most occurring element amongst a np.array python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the most occurring elements inside this np.array

```
[[ 2  8 15 ..., 10  4 16]
 [ 2  7 18 ..., 20 14 21]
 [ 3  4 15 ...,  1 24  6]
  ...,
 [ 8  0 18 ..., 17  3 14]
 [ 3 34 39 ...,  8 35 38]
 [ 8  3 14 ..., 18 10  6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job.

```
(values,counts) = np.unique(input_array, return_counts=True)

# Sort values according to count.
values = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(counts,values), reverse = True)]

top_n = 10
print(values[:top_n])
```